# Start cron jobs in docker-compose from host?

Tags: docker, cron, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml with some containers. I need to start command inside one of docker-compose container. I've tried this

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f ~/directory/to/docker-compose.yml  run --rm -T -w /var/www php /var/www/bin/yii bigquery/events
```

But didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem. You just need to change full docker-compose path before command execution!

```
* * * * * cd ~/directory/to/your/docker-compose && /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f ~/directory/to/docker-compose.yml run --rm -T -w /var/www php /var/www/bin/yii bigquery/events
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `docker-compose exec` instead, `docker-compose run` runs the command in a new container.

Comment: if I run this command `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f ~/directory/to/docker-compose.yml  run --rm -T -w /var/www php /var/www/bin/yii bigquery/events` locally it works. But when I start this command in cron it didn't work.

Comment: in my logs file I have next: The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The NGINX_CONF variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The MONGO_DATABASE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The MONGO_USERNAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The MONGO_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The Compose file '/path/to/docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.nginx.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object